# Design java swing jframes

Tags: java, netbeans

I work with java swing application .i want to design frame1(Main) consists three parts. Header space.and sidebar(left-jpannel).then remaining area body like website.Sidebar consists three jbuttons if click the button1 i want to display jframe2 in body area.and click button2 close jframe2 display jframe3 in body area.Like body changes in webapplication if click the botton.Any possible ways please suggest me.

package javaapplication8;

public class Mainframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form Mainframe
 */
public Mainframe() {
    initComponents();

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 153, 255));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Side bar"));
    jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 255));

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("jButton3");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setText("jButton4");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jButton4))
            .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addGap(57, 57, 57)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
            .addComponent(jButton4)
            .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 255));
    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Header"));

    jLabel1.setText("NOT CHANGE");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(61, 61, 61)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(75, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Body"));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 436, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     frame1 n = new frame1();
    n.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    frame2 n = new frame1();
    n.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   frame3 n = new frame1();
    n.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  frame4 n = new frame1();
    n.setVisible(true);
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Mainframe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

If click jbutton1 new frame open.but i want to change body area and display frame2 .Like web application.

Comment: I suggest you to use separate `JPanel` for center body instead of saying `JFrame`, Set your Main Frame's layout `BorderLayout`. It will help your design. Show us your code at-least to get more help